# Why isn't my batch file working? MsiExec + Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-installer

```
@echo off
color b
Echo Installing
start /wait msiexec.exe /l*v "log.log" /qn /i installer.msi
Echo Done!
timeout 2
```

My batch script code doesn't work it requires administrator privileges to execute the msiexec.exe command above

I've tried right clicking the batch script and run as administrator and that doesn't work but when I open up an administrative command prompt and run the

```
start /wait msiexec.exe /l*v "log.log" /qn /i installer.msi
```

It does work. I've tried running the /a switch on the command above like this:

```
start /wait msiexec.exe /l*v "log.log" /qn /i /a installer.msi
```

and that doesn't work either

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: Your generic issue is you aren't using full unambiguous paths. `msiexec.exe /l*v "c:\somewhere\log.log" /qn /i "c:\somewhere\installer.msi"`. There is no need for start.

Comment: ...and I strongly recommend to write `start "" /WAIT ...`, since the `start` command might interprete the first quoted string as the window title rather than something else (path,...); the `""` forces `start` to use an empty title; and PLEASE provide s *specific* question title; "Why isn't my batch file working?" is *not* quite specific... thank you!